# The method '~/' was called on null flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

When i call my countdown widget, I have this exception :

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Countdown(dirty, state: _CountdownState#97b4a):
>   The method '~/' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: ~/(3600)
>
> User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
>       Container
>
> init state null

After 1ms, my countdown print in my appbar and it's good, but why ?

```
class IneatAppBarPollWidget {
  getAppBar(String title, String logo, Candidate candidate) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
      leading: Image.asset(
        logo,
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        height: 32,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin:EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: new Countdown(),
              ),
              new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Text(
                  '${candidate.firstname[0].toUpperCase()}.${candidate.lastname[0].toUpperCase()}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Countdown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountdownState createState() => _CountdownState();
}

class _CountdownState extends State<Countdown> {
  Timer _timer;
  int seconds;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        constructTime(seconds),
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      ),
    );
  }

  String constructTime(int seconds) {
    int hour = seconds ~/ 3600;
    int minute = seconds % 3600 ~/ 60;
    int second = seconds % 60;
    return formatTime(hour) +
        ":" +
        formatTime(minute) +
        ":" +
        formatTime(second);
  }

  String formatTime(int timeNum) {
    return timeNum < 10 ? "0" + timeNum.toString() : timeNum.toString();
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    getDate();
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getDate() async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    String creationDate = await Poll().getCreationDateToSF();
    DateTime creationDateTime = DateTime.parse(creationDate);
    seconds = creationDateTime.difference(now).inSeconds;
  }

  void startTimer() {
    const period = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(period, (timer) {
      setState(() {
        seconds--;
      });
      if (seconds == 0) {
        cancelTimer();
      }
    });
  }

  void cancelTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    cancelTimer();
  }
}
```

Comment: without you showing us your Countdown() widget, i dont see how we might be helpful here.

Comment: @Marc i edited my post, sorry

Comment: just a wild guess... its perhaps an initialisation issue with seconds or timer instance variable?

Comment: ok maybe ... but why after 1ms i have the result in my appbar ? @Marc

Comment: the mistake happens is to the method getDate with creationDate String but why ? @Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is rendered before `seconds` is set. You should assign an init value for `second`.

```
int seconds = 0;
```

Comment: ok thank you ! now i don't have any error but I have 0 first print before my countdown ? Can i resolve it ?

Comment: You can add check for 0 at beginning of `constructTime` method:
`if (seconds == 0) return "";`

Comment: ok yes it's good, i have always this 1ms before the print countdown but it's good thank you